# Facing difficulty in Installation of Interactive Ruby shell and ruby in ubuntu 13.04 and getting started with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana3

Accidently I have installed both versions of ruby on my system and now the default version is set to
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
but I need to set the default version to 2.0.0...
for this I used the command 
$ rvm 2.0.0p294 --default
but it says rvm is not currently installed though I installed it, typing various commands(via google) .
Also I want to install an Integrated Ruby shell in ubuntu 13.04, do suggest how to do it.
I have also installed Aptana Studio on my system, now how should I get started with it.
Finally, the last problem is tell me how to check whether rails is currently installed in my system or not...
Thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use a gemset try writing
rvm use ruby_gemset_version

to check the rails version try to type rails -v

Comment: when I type the first command "ruby_gemset_version" it says "ruby_gemset_version: command not found"
when I do:
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.14
but I need Rails 4.0
how do I upgrade to it...??

Comment: please check this link to install rails 4
http://programminginrubyonrails.blogspot.in/2013/08/upgrade-to-rails-4-and-ruby-2.html

Comment: and to check your gemset version please type in the console rvm list

Comment: I installed "rvm" using the command "\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable" given in the site "http://rvm.io/" it shows that it has been successfully installed but when I type this command "rvm get head " it shows "The program 'rvm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install ruby-rvm" ... ?? do help .... thanx in advance!!

Comment: check this command 
"source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && type rvm | head -n 1 && rvm use ruby-version_you_you_want_to_use" type this without quote and provide the correct version

Comment: command typed by me... "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && type rvm | head -n 1 && rvm use 2.0.0"
output: "bash: /root/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory"
P.S. I am typing all the commands as root...

Comment: when i try to install rvm using the command "sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm" it shows... "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby-rvm"... :( ..... need urgent help..

Comment: not able to figure out your problem.. can you check what is showing if you type rvm list

Comment: it's showing "The program 'rvm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install ruby-rvm"
and I have installed rvm like 5 times on mah system.. !!

Comment: finally done.......actually multiple versions of ruby was installed on the system...I removed them using synaptics then I reinstalled ruby,rails and aptana... now it's working fine
P.C. sorry can't mark ur answer accepted :( ... 
P.P.C : can't upvote since I don't have enough credit.....

Answer (score 0):

you have to install RVM (ruby version manager), then you have control to use any specific versions of ruby, and coming to rails you have to manually install rails gem once you have installed rvm and selected a version.
This would be helpful to install rvm
https://rvm.io/rvm/install

After installation you have to install ruby versions.
Then you can use the following cmd
$ rvm use 2.0.0 
to use ruby 2.0.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this http://rvm.io/rvm/install It has instruction to install and cofigure RVM. It is dependant on CURL lib. So make sure you have curl installed in your system, if not then the command is

```
#sudo apt-get install curl
```

Once it is intalled and configured properly.

On Ubuntu:
GoTo Terminal > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > Set checkbox for (Run command as login shell)

Install rubies using rvm install.

Comment: already installed curl..... rvm is the main problem... see the previous comments.. if you wanna know about the problem....

Comment: Oh! For this goto Terminal > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > Set checkbox for (Run command as login shell)

Comment: thanx, atleast this worked for me.... if you have idea, do look into other issues as well.... !!

Comment: Please vote up my answer if it really helped you. The issue is ubuntu uses Gnome shell, which does'nt run login scripts.

Comment: man vote up requires 15 reputations and I am a newbie on stack... sure would have done that.....

Comment: I think, You can vote up or mark it as best answer for your own questions